# Nickel 500 and 200 ohms at 0 Celsius

Tags: rtd

I'm trying to find resistance table for Ni 500 and Ni 200. I found tables for Ni 1000, Ni 100, NiFe 604 and NiFe 507.7. But I wasn't able to find resistance to temperature table for Ni 500 and Ni 200. Could you please give me these tables? Or is it possible to convert Ni 1000 resistance values to Ni 500 and Ni 200. For example is it valid :

(Resistance of Ni 500) * 2 : find this value from table of Ni 1000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can calculate the Tables by using this formula for Ni xxx:
[image]

[image: For]= 100Ω for `Ni100`, 500Ω for Ni500 and so on.

```
t = temperature in °C
A = 5,485∙10^(−3) °C^(-1);
B = 6,65∙10^(−6) °C^(−2); 
C = 2,805∙10^(−11) °C^(−4); 
D = −2∙10^(−17) °C^(−6).
```

For Ni 500 you will get this:

[image: For Ni 500 you will get this:]

source is the [german wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widerstandsthermometer). (the english one does not have it)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your formula is correct. The resistance of Ni1000(T) is exactly 2\$\cdot\$ Ni500(T), so you can just use your existing tables (provided you know they match the sensor).

There are a number of different Nickel curves, depending on the exact sensor you have. The most common in Europe is the DIN 43760 standard, but there are others.

[Here](http://www.tnp-instruments.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/ni_100f_table.pdf) is one with \$\alpha\$= 0.00618 (DIN standard).

Another common "standard" is \$\alpha\$= 0.00672. For example, [this](http://www.rtdcompany.com/technical_info/table_display_ni_672.cfm) one.